# Using two equals signs in Visual Basic 2008

Tags: vb.net, variable-assignment, equality

In code, why wouldn't this work?

```
intMax = intTopValue = 20
```

Comment: Hungarian notation is frowned upon. Don't put `int` in the variable name.

Comment: @SLaks  Is there an actual problem with Hungarian notation?  Could this be simply another matter of religious conflict?

Comment: @nick - Hungarian notation is frowned upon for all .NET development: See section 2.6 in http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brada/archive/2005/01/26/361363.aspx - even in VB.NET.

Answer (score 8):

This is interpreted as `intMax = (intTopValue = 20)`.

`intTopValue = 20` will check whether `intTopValue` is equal to `20` and return true or false.
This boolean will then be assigned to `intMax`.

Most languages don't have this issue, since they use separate operators for assignment (`=` or `:=`) and equality (`==` or `=`).

By contrast, VB shares `=` for both operations.  Therefore, when `a = b` is written as an expression, it always means equality.

Comment: I am a beginner, so I'm trying to understand this, but is it valid that- VB reads the left of an equation as the answer side and the right of the equation as the equation itself?  The two equal signs told VB that intMax was equal to an undeclared variable.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're saying.  Do not think of this as an equation.  This is an _assignment_ - it assigns `intMax` to an expression.

Comment: Oh ok i see... that makes more sense thank you.  If you have anything else to add i would appreciate it.

Comment: Some languages also may have double assignment, i.e. A=B=C means to assign value of C to both A and B. So, this construction is quite ambiguous, to say at least. I would not recommend to use it in any programming language.

Comment: @MikeKeskinov: In every language but VB, `=` is a normal operator that assigns to the left operand and evaluates to the value assigned, so that's parsed as `A = (B = C)`, and `B = C` evaluates to `C`.  This is normal syntax.